# How to obtain a list of JS files from enabled modules, or expose such list from a theme as library?

Tags: javascript, theming

I'm in the [process](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/88083/16495) of extending [jQuery Multi](https://drupal.org/project/jqmulti) module. [Libraries API](https://drupal.org/project/libraries) libraries was built in, I have already added support for JavaScript libraries [provided by modules](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/88084/16495), so with minimal cooperation on the side of modules' authors I have that part covered. Now time to add **themes** to the list - and I'm stuck.

I found no way to make a theme use [`hook_library()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_library/7) and by the API docs it's a module hook, so I can't use method I used for modules.

I can use [`list_themes()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/list_themes/7) to list themes, but how to see a JS files?

Comment: I hope to see alternatives. Module's way of exporting libraries would fit my needs way better.

Answer (score 0):

[`list_themes()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/list_themes/7) returns an array of objects:

> The keys are the themes' machine names and the values are objects having the following properties:
>
> - **scripts**: An associative array of JavaScripts, using the filename as key and the complete filepath as value. Not set if no scripts are defined in the .info file.